# Want to display file list using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I am new to netbeans with glassfish server.My html code looks like,

```
<html>
    <body>
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.java">
    <div style="float:center">
        <center>
            Select a file:
            <input type="file" name="first" />
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="upload" />
        </center>
    </div>
    <center>
        </br>
        </br>
        <iframe id="upload" style="background-color:white;" width=90% height=80%></iframe>
    </center>                
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when the request is submitted,i want to store the uploaded file in drive(ex.c:/upload) and the iframe(id=upload) should display the files in folder(c:/upload). Does anyone know where I can find some sample code that shows how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process HTTP `multipart/form-data` requests in a servlet, use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). You should end up with the uploaded file in a [`FileItem`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html). It has a `write()` method.

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName()); 
fileItem.write(new File("c:/upload", filename)); // Name must be unique!
```

For the usage guide and more code examples, just check their [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html).

---

To display a list of files in the folder, you need to use the [`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API, it has a `listFiles()` method which returns a list of all files (paths) in a certain path. Do it in a preprocessing [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which forwards the request to a JSP to display the list.

```
File[] files = new File("c:/upload").listFiles();
request.setAttribute("files", files);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/uploads.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In the `/WEB-INF/uploads.jsp` file use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>` to iterate over the `File[]`.

```
<c:forEach items="${files}" var="file">
    <c:out value="${file.name}" /> (${file.length / 1024}KB)<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that this is of course open for more (UI) finetuning, but that's up to you. I assume that you already know the HTML/JSP/Servlet basics.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like that

```
     <%!
      Object path;
      public void getDirectory(String path, Vector files, Vector folder){
      File directory=new File(path); 
     File []file=directory.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<file.length; i++){
       if(file[i].isDirectory()){
        folder.add(file[i].getName());
       }
       else{
        files.add(file[i].getName());
       }
    }
 }
 %>

<table>
<%

    path=session.getAttribute("fileName");
   Vector file=new Vector(), folder=new Vector();
  getDirectory("C:/FileFolderProject/WebContent/"+path,file,folder);
   out.println("<music>");

  for(int a=0; a<file.size(); a++){
    %>
     <tr>
     <td>
      <img src="images/editfileimg.jpg" alt="file">
      </td>
     <td>
     <% 
     out.println("<file>"+file.elementAt(a).toString()+"</file><br/>");
    %>
     </td>
     <tr>
  <%

  }
  out.println("</music>");
  %>
   </table>
```