# Displaying Files from a folder in Jsp dropdown and reading from them on selection

Tags: file, jsp

I want to display all files from a particular folder in a JSP dropdown and upon selection i want to display all the details in it.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778525/want-to-display-file-list-using-jsp

Comment: You can't unless you're talking about files on the server.

Comment: No guys actually what i listed the files in the directory to a array.
and displayed that in the select.
And then got the filepath and then called the BufferedReader File Reader to do the remaining work.
@developerwjk
Thanks for your suggestion though :)

Comment: ^@Satya : I got it . i did it in above method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to list the files in the folder

```
public class ListFiles 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Directory path here
        String path = "."; 

        String files;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
            {
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                System.out.println(files);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then display the array in select

```
<select><option>array values</option><select>
```

and then upon select read from the files

```
using BufferedReader..
```